How does Wasm code run in browsers and how does it interact with JavaScript
I'm curious about how WebAssembly (Wasm) code operates in the browser. I understand that JavaScript code in the browser is executed by the JavaScript engine, but I'm unsure about who executes the Wasm binary. Is it also the JavaScript engine?
Additionally, I'd like to understand how asynchronous JavaScript functions interact with Wasm. When we load a Wasm binary through JavaScript and call an exported Wasm function, it's added to the JavaScript call stack. But what happens if the Wasm function calls an asynchronous JavaScript function inside its body? Is the callback of the asynchronous function added to the JS queue stack? Do JS and Wasm share the same call stack and event queue, or do they each have their own? If they each have their own stacks and queues, how do they coordinate execution?
Let's say in Wasm module we import JS async function and call it in one of our wasm functions
(import "env" "async_js"
(func $async_js (param i32) (result i32))) 
    
(func $fnc (result i32)   
  (call $async_js (i32.const 1))
  ;;  other code here  
)

Now in js when the wasm module is loaded we call the fnc function
wasm.instance.exports.fnc()

So, the JS async function is called, the callback of the JS async function is added to the js queue stack and the rest of the wasm fnc function is executed, right? but how does the browser know where to continue or how to switch between wasm and js?

There is a Javascript program that interprets the Wasm byte code.  The only thing your browser runs in Javascript.

@TimRoberts Not quite, this is how it works according to MDN: WebAssembly Concepts -> With the advent of WebAssembly appearing in browsers, the virtual machine that we talked about earlier will now load and run two types of code — JavaScript AND WebAssembly.

WASM cannot have direct access to browser API, it must be called via JS. There is no garbage collection like JS so you need to maintain that. Older browsers lack support. There's a slower startup when loading pages generally.
WebAssembly (Wasm) binary is not executed by the JavaScript engine. Instead, it is executed by a separate component in the browser called the Wasm engine (which may have varying support with older browsers). Same environment but different engines...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@BGPHiJACK: WASM added support for garbage collection not so long ago. Shipped with Chrome 119.

@Live: the ability to call async JS from WASM, the JSPI, is slowly making its way to browsers but it's still not there for everyone.

@BGPHiJACK, the intro page on the WebAssembly website states: "WebAssembly is designed to maintain the versionless, feature-tested, and backwards-compatible nature of the web. WebAssembly modules will be able to call into and out of the JavaScript context and access browser functionality through the same Web APIs accessible from JavaScript. WebAssembly also supports non-web embeddings." To me, as a WASM-noob, it seems that WASM VMs in newer browsers will be able to directly access browser functionality, just like their JavaScript engine can. Or am I mistaken?

@BartHofland, you are mistaken. What that sentence means is "through the same JavaScript Web API", i.e. you have to call through JS imports. That is very much intentional, Wasm code itself is 100% sandboxed and cannot access the environment without explicitly being given such imports.

WebAssembly does not currently support awaiting promises, so the code you provided would not work as you might expect.
Async Javascript functions always return a Promise object. Your imported "async" function declared as (func $async_js (param i32) (result i32)) has an i32 return type, which means that it is not async.
Instead of WebAssembly awaiting the function call, what actually happens is the returned Javascript Promise object gets converted to an integer (which happens to be 0) when passing it to WebAssembly, and your WebAssembly function returns immediately. To be clear, the called async function still executes, and its callback is added to the queue stack as normal, but it would not "continue" into the wasm code as it was never "awaited" there. The code snippet below shows this behaviour:


void async function(){
  "use strict";
  // `binary` is the compiled version of the following WAT code:
  // (module
  //   (import "env" "asyncJs" (func $async_js (param i32) (result i32)))
  //   (func $fnc (export "fnc") (result i32)   
  //     i32.const 1
  //     call $async_js
  //   )
  // )
  const binary = new Uint32Array([1836278016,1,1610746369,2130804481,2130772064,50401026,125202021,1853453153,7555683,16909056,17237761,1668179459,134873344,1090520577,184553473,1845763584,23424353,134218256,1853453153,1936351075,1852179201,33882723,65536]).buffer;
  const module = new WebAssembly.Module(binary);
  const instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module, {
    "env": {
      "asyncJs": async function(){
        // Wait for a second
        await new Promise(resolve => window.setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        document.body.append(document.createTextNode(`Awaited timeout.`));
        return 1;
      }
    }
  });
  const start = new Date;
  const result = await instance.exports.fnc(); // The await here does nothing because WebAssembly functions are never async!
  const duration = new Date - start;
  document.body.append(document.createTextNode(`Result: ${result}, which took ${duration}ms.`));
}();



You should see how the WebAssembly function returns 0 immediately, and the async function prints a message after its async task resolves (in this case, a one second timer). The return value of the async function (1) is not used anywhere.
The Javascript Promise Integration WebAssembly proposal aims to add functionality where imported async functions can "suspend" the WebAssembly stack until the called function resolves (or rejects) the promise. However, this proposal has not been fully implemented by any browser or WebAssembly runtime, and is not shipped by default in any browser.
As of now, the only way to successfully obtain the value of a promise from WebAssembly is to completely return out of the current execution stack, and to later receive a callback from Javascript after the promise resolves.
To answer your other question, it is important to note that all WebAssembly functions can be treated like any other Javascript function: they can be called, they may call other Javascript (or WebAssembly) functions, and they may return a value. There is no way to determine whether a function executes Javascript or WebAssembly code.
Effectively, this means that when a WebAssembly function is called, it is added to the call stack like normal, and there is no reason to have separate stacks as all WebAssembly code runs synchronously. So, you could think of the Javascript engine executing both Javascript and WebAssembly code, even though an implementation may choose to compile and execute WebAssembly code in a different way to Javascript code.
